# The bind model is null during the post request

Tags: asp.net-core, post, model-binding

I have this problem with model binding in asp.net core. I have a model which contains attributes and a list of another model. When I submit the model to display, it works properly. I used the debugger to track the values and the model in the razor view becomes null when I perform the post request via form submit. Please help me.

I am currently using Asp.net core 2.2 MVC and i am using asp-for tag to link the form attribute to the model.

```
<div class="row">
<form asp-action="Edit" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input hidden asp-for="@Model.UserId" />
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for=@Model.Username></label>
            <input readonly asp-for=@Model.Username class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for=@Model.Username class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for=@Model.Name></label>
            <input readonly asp-for=@Model.Name class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for=@Model.Name class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for=@Model.Email></label>
            <input readonly asp-for=@Model.Email class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for=@Model.Email class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row ml-1 form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            Template
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            Entity
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 ">
            Role Assigned
        </div>
        @for (int i= 0; i < Model.EntityUserList.Count(); i++)
        {
            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].TemplateId" />
            <div class="my-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @Model.EntityUserList[i].TemplateName
            </div>

            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].EntityId" />
            <div class="my-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                @Model.EntityUserList[i].EntityTitle
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 row ml-1">
                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsSubmitter">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsSubmitter">
                        Submitter
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsApprover">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsApprover">
                        Approver
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox my-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsAdmin">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" asp-for="@Model.EntityUserList[i].IsAdmin">
                        Admin
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </div>




    <div class="form-group mt-3 ml-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-3" />
        <a asp-controller="UserManagement" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-info" style="width:auto">
            Cancel
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I perform the post method, the model throws me a null reference exception.

Comment: Please add `Edit` action code with binded model

Comment: `When I perform the post method, the model throws me a null reference exception.` which code show the error?`

Comment: @Alexander: I alr had my Edit action with binded model and it is written like this :

[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditResult(string id, UserManagementEditViewModel model)
{
  // business logic
}

Comment: Xing Zou:  @for (int i= 0; i < Model.EntityUserList.Count(); i++) { ... } this part shows the error according to my debugging tool;

Comment: Btw guys, I have solved it by changing my action name in the controller. I don't know why when I submit the form, the code always run to the HttpGet method of Edit action instead of HttpPost. After I changed the action name from Edit to something like EditResult, it works perfectly. Can anyone explain to me this strange behavior?

Comment: It's strange and it should not be...Maybe you could check the generated url from browser  or your routing configuration

Comment: @XingZou: I checked already, but there is nothing wrong with configuration. I still don't know how this is possible.

Comment: Your <form> tag use `asp-action="Edit"` then your controller name should be `Edit` too.They are equired to be the same.

Comment: @XingZou: yes, I understand. I alr had Edit action my controller, however, the problem is that it never points to that Edit action. In my controller, there are two Edit action which are [HttpGet] Edit and [HttpPost] Edit. By right, it should point to the [HttpPost] after the form submits, but it points to [HttpGet] instead. Strange behavior